# cannot call stock dialer for emergency calls

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, phone-call, android-dialer

I am testing a third party system app dialer for a start up carrier. I have tested it on a Galaxy S3 and S5, it works perfect. Dialing 911 redirects to stock dialer and calls out. I have a Coolpad device to test on and when in system partition dialing 911 does nothing. I get this error in the logcat, any idea what would be causing this because I'm lost. Is it that the developer has defined a Samsung activity rather than using an intent for emergency calls? Or have i done something while integrating this into system?

```
V/OutgoingCallBroadcaster( 1304):  - Checking restrictions for number '911':
V/OutgoingCallBroadcaster( 1304):      isExactEmergencyNumber     = true
V/OutgoingCallBroadcaster( 1304):      isPotentialEmergencyNumber = true
W/OutgoingCallBroadcaster( 1304): Cannot call potential emergency number '911' with CALL Intent Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:xxx flg=0x800000 cmp=com.android.phone/.OutgoingCallBroadcaster }.
I/OutgoingCallBroadcaster( 1304): Launching default dialer instead...
V/OutgoingCallBroadcaster( 1304): onCreate(): calling startActivity for Dialer: Intent { act=android.intent.action.DIAL dat=tel:xxx cmp=com.android.incallui/com.android.dialer.DialtactsActivity }
I/ActivityManager( 1304): Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.android.incallui time:4344421
I/ActivityManager(  927): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.DIAL dat=tel:xxx cmp=com.android.incallui/com.android.dialer.DialtactsActivity} from pid 1304
E/OutgoingCallBroadcaster( 1304): calling startActivity for Dialer: 
E/OutgoingCallBroadcaster( 1304): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.incallui/com.android.dialer.DialtactsActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
E/OutgoingCallBroadcaster( 1304):   at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
E/OutgoingCallBroadcaster( 1304):   at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
E/OutgoingCallBroadcaster( 1304):   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3430)
E/OutgoingCallBroadcaster( 1304):   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3391)
E/OutgoingCallBroadcaster( 1304):   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3633)
E/OutgoingCallBroadcaster( 1304):   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3601)
E/OutgoingCallBroadcaster( 1304):   at com.android.phone.OutgoingCallBroadcaster.processIntent(OutgoingCallBroadcaster.java:620)
E/OutgoingCallBroadcaster( 1304):   at com.android.phone.OutgoingCallBroadcaster.onCreate(OutgoingCallBroadcaster.java:389)
E/OutgoingCallBroadcaster( 1304):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5237)
E/OutgoingCallBroadcaster( 1304):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
E/OutgoingCallBroadcaster( 1304):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
E/OutgoingCallBroadcaster( 1304):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2248)
E/OutgoingCallBroadcaster( 1304):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
E/OutgoingCallBroadcaster( 1304):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1199)
E/OutgoingCallBroadcaster( 1304):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/OutgoingCallBroadcaster( 1304):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/OutgoingCallBroadcaster( 1304):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5061)
E/OutgoingCallBroadcaster( 1304):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/OutgoingCallBroadcaster( 1304):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/OutgoingCallBroadcaster( 1304):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:780)
E/OutgoingCallBroadcaster( 1304):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:596)
E/OutgoingCallBroadcaster( 1304):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
V/OutgoingCallBroadcaster( 1304): At the end of onCreate(). isFinishing(): true
```

Comment: You seem to be trying to specify a particular component in your `Intent`? Why? And what is your code for doing that? You seem to be requesting an activity that does not exist.

Comment: I'm not the app developer, it my job to add the app to system partition test it and upload the system image. Just wanted to make sure it wasn't something i did for it to quit working

Comment: Maybe it would be better to use `Intent.ACTION_CALL_EMERGENCY` instead of `Intent.ACTION_CALL`. Have a look at the [Android source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/services/Telephony/+/kitkat-cts-dev/src/com/android/phone/OutgoingCallBroadcaster.java#525).

Comment: Thank you looks like that is the issue, i will let the app developer know to fix it.